# Google oAuth prob. Google Sign in is disabled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I am using a script that checks if current active email is registered in our sheet later on we noticed that the script gives us an error called "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" we send a review for this concern with the google and this the reply. My question is how can I achieve this? what is the proper way to solve this .thnx[image]

Here is my code.

```
function doGet() {
  var HR_SprdSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Awesome Sheet Link Here :D");
  var HR_Sheet = HR_SprdSheet.getSheetByName("Email Registration");
  var Email_Range = HR_Sheet.getRange("A3:A");
  var Email_Values = Email_Range.getDisplayValues();
  var Appl_Email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var message; 

  var notfound = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("notfound.html");
  var sample = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("sample .html");

  for (var i = 0; i < Email_Values.length; i++) { 
    if (Email_Values[i][0] == Appl_Email) {        
      message = 1;                                 
      break;                                       
    } else {                                       
      message = 0;                                  
    }                                              
  }                                               

  if (message == 1) {
    return sample ;
  } else {
    Logger.log(1);
    return notfound;
  }
}
```

Here is the scopes

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to authenticate to google.  You are using the wrong scopes you need to change it.

Comment: Noted sir I will edit my question

Comment: done adding my code

Comment: Thats not your authentication code i need to see what scopes you are requesting when you authenticate the user.

Comment: Where I can find that?

Comment: I added an Image is that the scope your asking?

Comment: Its been a while since i have done this in app script does it create a project over on https://console.developers.google.com?

Comment: i didnt use any project on console.developers.google.com when creating this.

Comment: Is that your complete list of scopes? calling `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` typically triggers additional scopes.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. thats my only scope. is there any other way to get the current active email aside `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` i need the email so i can check if the email exist in my sheet